# How to enable Ultimate Performance Power Plan in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, power-management, windows-10-v1803

There is the new "Ultimate Performance" Power Plan, but how can I enable it?

Comment: This was flagged as [VLQ](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/760795), which I think is not uncalled for, as detailed documentations are easily found via google, eg. [Add Ultimate Performance Power Plan in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/107613-add-remove-ultimate-performance-power-plan-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Looks as though it was asked to be answered, which is not against the rules. But it was asked in a way that indicates little to no effort to solve, which, considering it was answered right away is probably intended and not unexpected. @asesjix, thanks for adding this relevant and useful knowledge to SU. It may be helpful, in order to avoid "Very Low Quality" flags in the future, to flesh your question out a little more, even if you already have the answer and intend to post it.

Comment: The fact we're getting more answers here is a net positive so long as they are not plagiarized or copied without appropriate attribution.

Answer (score 0):

The "Ultimate Performance" power plan exists since Windows 10 Version 1803.
To activate the Power Plan, the following steps must be taken:

1. Open *cmd.exe* as *Administrator*
2. Duplicate the scheme with: `powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61`
3. Copy the guid from ultimate plan
4. Set the ultimate plan active with: `powercfg /setactive <GUID>`

[image]