# Dell G5 5587 Intel Core i7 8750H throttling

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu, intel-core-i7, throttling

I have a problem with my laptop Dell G5 5587 and its CPU Intel Core i7 8750H.
I have bought this laptop in December last year and since then I've encountered a power throttling on CPU (more specifically, **PL1 limit**), despite this being a 'Gaming laptop'.

The symptom is as follows: when gaming, or doing any other CPU+GPU intensive task, the laptop decides to lower Power Limit to 15W from standard 45W and the CPU throttles to 0.8 GHz from 4.0GHz on Turbo.

The configuration is the following:

- Dell G5 5587 chassis
- Intel Core i7 8750H 6x2.2GHz (up to 4.2 GHz)
- 16 GB DDR4-2666 RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX1060 Max-Q Design with 6 GB VRAM
- Toshiba 512GB M2 SSD
- Samsung 860 EVO 1TB SSD
- 15.6" 4K HDR screen
- Windows 10 x64 Enterprise Insider Preview Version 20H1 Build 18865 + Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I have tried everything, including what I've found on the Internet:

- Update BIOS (several times, it came with v.1.5.1, I'm now on v.1.9.0)
- Update drivers (all of them)
- Update Windows (obviously) and all the software I have
- Followed several guides for this particular CPU, including undervolting the CPU and cache, as well as reducing Turbo boost speeds
- Removed Intel DPTF following this guide [Removing Intel DPTF for good](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/7byhjq/disabling_intel_dptf_for_good/)
- Disabled Turbo Boost
- Contacted Dell Support, which turned out to be pointless, as I had to spend around a week to explain to them the problem, and that I'm not stupid and I have all the updates. I provided them with log files to show the behavior of the system
- Installed Dell Power Manager and set cooling to Ultra-Performance

As you can see, I've reached an impasse and I was wondering maybe the respected community of Stack Exchange could help me out :-)
I haven't done extensive testing under Linux, though, but I don't remember anything like this happening there. So this seems to be particularly Windows problem.

Only other choice I have left is to wait for 9th Gen Intel CPUs to come out and exchange the laptop under warranty.

**EDIT**
I'm using Windows 10 x64 Enterprise Insider Preview Version 20H1 Build 18865 (obviously updated more than dozen of times already)

**UPDATE 1:**
As recommended in comments, I have enabled the Ultimate Performance battery mode, but it didn't help either.
I have also followed this [Guide to prevent PL1 limit from changing](https://medium.com/@n4ru/45w-performance-from-15w-kaby-lake-r-d8d5e7ea4fad). But it didn't help either.

Comment: I would get rid of all the Dell software.  I would then enable the [Ultimate Performance](https://www.howtogeek.com/368781/how-to-enable-ultimate-performance-power-plan-in-windows-10/) power plan.  I would also then remove your meta-commentary from your question.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment to include this vital important necessary information required to answer your question.

Comment: You might also want to indicate which version of Windows 10 you are using.  You can determine this by providing a screenshot of the ouput of `winver`

Comment: @Ramhound, indicated Windows version in the question

Comment: @Ramhound, also, only Dell software I have is Dell Power Manager, which I installed after encountering the proble, in order to test things. It didn't change anything, so I can remove it, but it won't change anything either

Comment: Did you enable the power plan I suggested?  Did this problem exist on a supported version of Windows 10.  2003 (20H1) is extremely early for production use.

Comment: @Ramhound, there is no such plan, there is only Balanced with the control of performance in battery panel taskbar set to Best performance.
Btw, I've never seen Ultra performance power plan in Windows, only High performance. As for the version of Windows, the problem first occured on version 1809 back in December, since then I've had Insider builds of version 19H1 (1903), as well as 20H1 (2003). I'm planning on staying on the stable version when 1903 is released. In any case, I wouldn't have started asking around, if the problem was only on one build, as I understand the idea behind betas

Comment: based on the amount of complaints on the Internet, this also seems to be a global problem, not only for Dell laptops, but Lenovo as well, and not something happening only specifically to my laptop

Comment: There absolutely is an Ultimate Performance power plan.  I linked to documentation that explained how to enable it.  My question still stands, have you enabled it, and tried the plan?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1327298/how-to-enable-ultimate-performance-power-plan-in-windows-10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92220/discussion-between-ramhound-and-george-salukvadze).

Comment: @Ramhound any thoughts?

Comment: Not an expert on Windows Laptops, but maybe I could suggest you to check your battery health? On Macbook Pros, this kind of throttling is strongly tied to battery health (since the computer uses battery - even when on power cord - to sustain peak power demands).

Comment: @MarceloMyara, thanks for the advice. I did check it with Dell Power Manager, I will try with 3rd party software. But in any case, I've bought the laptop in the end of December last year, so it's new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many months of struggling, I've been able to at least partially solve this problem.

First and foremost, download and install ASUS GPU Tweak II, then go to Advanced mode and increase the thermal limit by one step (in my case it increased from 78 to 86 degrees). My laptop has been running GPU intensive workload for around 48 hours now.

Next, and this is not necessary - undervolt your CPU, which, apparently, has been disabled in the last several versions of Dell BIOS, so you may need to downgrade your BIOS. I would recommend undervolting the cores by 0.100-0.150 V and the cache by 0.075-0.125 V, depending on your silicon.

Next step for me - I will try Grizzly Kryonaut thermal paste instead of Arctic MX-4, based on reviews it further reduces temps by 5-7 degrees and this is what I'm hoping to get.

All in all, I've managed around 1 h of gaming without throttling and framerate drops, but when running GPU intensive workload for many hours CPU still throttles to 0.8 GHz due to power limit, which is weird.